# why is a wordcloud not generated in mathematica with this code?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, word-cloud

```
data = EntityValue[CountryData[], {"Name", "Population"}];
WordCloud[data]
```

All I get is this:

```
WordCloud[{{"Afghanistan", Quantity[35623235, "People"]}, {"Albania", 
   Quantity[3248655, "People"]}, {"Algeria", 
   Quantity[37473690, "People"]}, {"American Samoa", 
   Quantity[54719, "People"]}, {"Andorra", 
   Quantity[85458, "People"]}, {"Angola", .....
```

And not any graphic

Comment: works for me, what mathematica version?

Comment: mathematica version 10.0

Comment: the docs say wordcloud was  introduced in 10.1.  If it works for you at all you might try this `WordCloud[{#[[1]], QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]]} & /@ data]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a word cloud in version 10.0 by using Heike's [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2360/9490), but I had to remove the part concerning a custom distance function since it slows down this version unbelievably.

```
data = << "http://pastebin.com/raw/02YJ9Ntx";
range = {Min[data[[All, 2]]], Max[data[[All, 2]]]};
words = Style[#1, FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Bold, 
     FontColor -> 
      Hue[RandomReal[], RandomReal[{.5, 1}], RandomReal[{.5, 1}]], 
     FontSize -> Rescale[#2, range, {12, 70}]] & @@@ data;
wordsimg = 
  ImagePad[#, -3 - 
      BorderDimensions[#]] & /@ (Image[
       Graphics[Text[Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 2]]]] & /@ words);
wordsimgRot = 
  ImageRotate[#, RandomReal[2 Pi], Background -> White] & /@ wordsimg;
iteration2[img1_, w_] := 
 Module[{imdil, centre, diff, dimw, padding, padded1, minpos},
  dimw = ImageDimensions[w];
  padded1 = ImagePad[img1, {dimw[[1]] {1, 1}, dimw[[2]] {1, 1}}, 1];
  imdil = 
   Binarize[
    ImageCorrelate[Binarize[ColorNegate[padded1], 0.05], 
     Dilation[Binarize[ColorNegate[w], .05], 1]]];
  centre = ImageDimensions[padded1]/2;
  minpos = 
   Reverse@Nearest[Position[Reverse[ImageData[imdil]], 0], 
      Reverse[centre]][[1]];
  Sow[minpos - centre];
  diff = ImageDimensions[imdil] - dimw;
  padding[pos_] := Transpose[{#, diff - #} &@Round[pos - dimw/2]];
  ImagePad[#, (-Min[#] {1, 1}) & /@ BorderDimensions[#]] &@
   ImageMultiply[padded1, ImagePad[w, padding[minpos], 1]]]
```

Then you can get two different word clouds, with or without random rotations,

```
{Fold[iteration2, wordsimgRot[[1]], Rest@wordsimgRot],
 Fold[iteration2, wordsimg[[1]], Rest@wordsimg]}
```

[image]

These compare quite well with what you get in version 10.3 with `WordCloud[data]`

[image]